# How to highlight specific string in magento

Tags: php, magento

In my phtml  i m getting data from database

```
<?php $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$question = Mage::getModel('example/question')->load($id);
$answer = Mage::getModel('example/answer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', $id);
$i = 1;
?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Your Question View')?></h2>
<div class="que-view">
    <div><?php echo $this->__('<b>'.'Question:'.'</b>') . ' ' . $question->getQuestions();?></div>
    <span class='que-view-tag'><?php echo $this->__('<b>'.'Answer'.'</b>'. ' ')?></span>
    <?php foreach($answer as $ans):?>
        <p class='que-view-ans'><?php echo '<b>' .$i .')</b>'.' '.$ans->getAnswers();?></p>
        <?php $i++;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>

</div>
```

In above code i m using foreach to print answer now i m getting all ans from database but in specific ans i want to highlight that answer. specific answer means i want to check customer id is same or not if same than i want to highlight that answer how to do this

O/p like this

```
 Que: test
    Ans: Ans1 ( customerid = 1)
       (highlight this Ans)  Ans2 ( customerid = 2)
         Ans3( customerid = 3)
```

using this bracket() is just for u can understand

Comment: Could you show expected result in html? I don't clearly understand you, all appearances you need something like: p class='que-view-ans <?php if($customer->getId() == 555) echo 'make-bold'; ?>' and create css style for class 'make-bold'

Comment: u told me that using if condition in p tag that not possible because all ans have diff customer id . check my update

Comment: I still don't fully understand the question. Are you asking about the way how to highlight tag 'p'? Or you ask about type of highlighting? Or you need help to create a condition of customer check?

Comment: i want to highlight tag p with condition if id is 2 than that p tag is highlight if not same than display as simple no highlight understand or no

Comment: please, don't forget to put dots and commas.

Comment: ok highlight tag p with condition. if condition is true than highlight that answer,else condition is false than display p tag without highlight. is that possible add class in p tag with condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<p class='que-view-ans <?php if($a == $b) echo 'make-bold'; ?> '><?php echo '<b>' .$i .')</b>'.' '.$ans->getAnswers();?></p>
```

Don't forget create style for 'make-bold' class.